# Removing file in mutliple directory with specific line

Tags: linux, command-line, text-processing

I've got tree of folders like:

```
00 -- 0
   -- 1
   ...
   -- 9
 ...
99 -- 0 
   -- 1
   ...
   -- 9
```

In every folder I have .ini files with some kind od text.

How can I remove files which got `#` at beginning of second line?

I tried to use:

```
for i in {00..99}; do for b in {0..9}; do grep -LZ -- # *.ini | xargs
-r0 rm; done; done
```

but it didn't works. I wonder about using `sed` and `awk` to do it, but i don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a recent enough Awk and GNU `find` you can do

```
awk 'FNR==2 { if ($0 ~ /^#/) printf "%s\0", FILENAME; nextfile }' [0-9][0-9]/[0-9]/*.ini |
xargs -r0 echo rm
```

The [`nextfile` statement](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Nextfile-Statement.html) is a POSIX extension but might not be present in very old Awk implementations.  If your files are small, maybe just take out the `nextfile` and live with the minor inefficiency that we read through the end of each file even though we only really need to examine the second line.

The `-0` option to `xargs` is a GNU extension.  If your file names are guaranteed to not contain newlines, you can probably get away with

```
awk 'FNR==2 { if ($0 ~ /^#/) print FILENAME; nextfile }' [0-9][0-9]/[0-9]/*.ini |
xargs -r echo rm
```

Finally, remove the `echo` to actually remove the files it prints.

In some more detail, Awk processes each input file one line at a time, and evaluates the script on each separately.  The built-in variable `FNR` is set to the current line number within the file, and `FILENAME` is the current file's name.  The variable `$0` contains the entire line, and we check whether it matches the regular expression `^#` (beginning of line, immediately followed by a literal `#` character); if so, we print the `FILENAME`(otherwise, no output for this file). The `nextfile` command closes the current file and skips directly to the first input line of the next file in the argument list (or stops processing if no file names remain to be processed).

If you have a lot of matching files, you can't use a wildcard like that (you get "argument list too long"); if so, maybe simply revert back to the loop you had.

The immediate error in your attempt is that you need quotes around `#` (otherwise, it marks the rest of the line as a comment); but of course, your `grep` looks for that character anywhere in the file, and you didn't specify the path for the file to examine.  With the immediate errors fixed, that would be

```
# Don't use, still broken
for i in stuff; do
    for b in more stuff; do
        grep -LZ '#' "$i/$b"/*.ini
    done
done |
# or simply grep -LZ '#' [0-9][0-9]/[0-9]/*.ini
xargs -r0 echo rm
```

but again, you can't easily fix this to only look at the second line of each file. (Notice also how I run the final `xargs` outside the final `done`.)

Comment: can you please explain your awk code? I am trying to learn it somehow.  particularly your if statement is really complex.

Comment: Not really. It looks for the regular expression `^#` (start of line, hash sign) anywhere in the current input line `$0`.  The governing condition `FNR==2` causes this block to only be evaluated on the second line of the containing file.

Comment: @tripleee your comamnd didn't work unfortunately. All files got 3 lines. for practice I comment second linein every file  `for i in {00..99}; do for b in {0..9}; do sed -i -e '2s/^/#/' $i/$b/$i\_$b.ini; done; done` What mean in your code part in { } ? Sorry, but I'm not very high level linux

Comment: I have updated the answer to explain the Awk script. Is that what you mean by *code part in `{ }`?* The code works for me locally.

Comment: @tripleee everything clear in command after your update! but I tried your updated command and it still not work. It prints only `rm 0_00.ini etc` but not remove it

Comment: Yeah, remove the `echo` once you are confident it returns the correct results.

Comment: It's not clear how this is wrong or how to reproduce the problem. Can you fork the Ideone demo and change it so that it actually reproduces your problem?

Comment: The regex looks for `#` only at beginning of line, if you want to look anywhere on the line, take out the `^`

Comment: I tried your solution with your demo and it works. I have to reconfigure my work and I will see what happend. thanks a lot !